# SqlAlchemy "too many clients already" error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, sqlsoup

I'm fairly new to python and pyramid framework. Recently I was introduced to SQLSoup to take care of my database (postgres) needs.

```
dbEngine1 = SqlSoup(settings['sqlalchemy.db1.url'])
users = dbEngine1.users.fetchall()
```

Everything is working great, however after a short period of using the pyramid app, I'm getting this error message. I have to kill pyramid to release all idling connections in postgres (about 50 idling connection before throwing below exception)

```
sorry, too many clients already
```

My question is, how do I close this idling connection, I tried adding a line of code as shown below, but it does not help.

```
dbEngine1 = SqlSoup(settings['sqlalchemy.db1.url'])
users = dbEngine1.users.fetchall()
dbEngine1.engine.connect().close()
```

Any pointer from SQLAlchemy gurus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you create `dbEngine1` on each request to yours Pyramid app.

For proper usage SqlSoup in webapp you must use SA Sessions.

See section "Accessing the Session" on [this page](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/SqlSoup).

> how do I close this idling connection

SqlSoup such as raw SA use the connection pool, each connection in pool at idle status util query executes. This connection pool must be created once.

Comment: broken link for "Accessing the Session"